# How to iterate in feature file of cucumber

Tags: java, webdriver, cucumber, gradle

We are using cucumber in our automation project with webdriver. No Question is that if it is possible to have iteration in feature file. For example we need to run a method for 50 times. is there any way to call that method 50 times in feature file itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the loop construct directly in the feature file. This is not possible. There is no loop construct (for, while, ...) in Gherkin, the language used in feature files. Of course you can do iteration in your step definitions with standard Java/Ruby constructs as much as you like, but I'm sure you are aware of that.

The closest thing to iteration in Gherkin is maybe a step with a [multiline data table argument](http://cukes.info/step-definitions.html) (see section "Data Tables"). But this only serves to make it more transparent that "more one thing" happens in the step definition. Not sure if that is useful for you.

All that said: Why do you want that? You definitely should keep technical things like iterating 50 times over something *out* of the feature file and hide that in the step file. Use something like this:

Feature file:

```
....
When the user clicks the button 50 times
...
```

Step file (Java):

```
@When("the user clicks the button (\\d+) times")
public void theUserClicksTheButton(int howOften) {
  for (int i = 0; i < howOften; i++) {
    // do stuff for one click here
  }
}
```

Or, in Ruby:

```
When /^the user clicks the button (\d+) times$/ do |how_often|
  how_often.to_i.times do |count|
    # do stuff for one click here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call 50 times your method. I am using cucumber-ruby so I am describing below how to call method 50 times.

support/helper/test.rb

```
def test_method
end
```

feature/step_definitions/test_steps.rb

```
50.times do |count|
  test_method
end
```